# How to run an entire Python module from another Python module?

Tags: python

I have 2 python modules (modA.py and modB.py). I want to run modA.py from modB.py. How do I do that? If I import modA.py in modB.py, then I can access the functions and classes in modA.py, but how can I actually execute modA.py (all of it)?

Here's an example case:

-- modA.py --

```
print "Hello! I'm ModA"
```

How should I write modB.py so that after executing modB.py I get the output:

"Hello! I'm modA"

EDIT: In the comments it's mentioned that importing ***is*** executing the module. This is very helpful information. Thanks for that. However, there's a slight problem. What if I have:

--- modB.py ---

```
# execute modA.py
import modA.py 

print "some ModB.py stuff here"

# execute modA.py again
import modA.py
```

In this case, it doesn't execute modA.py a second time as it has already imported it. I guess maybe, is there a way to "unimport" the module? Even though, doesn't seem like an elegant solution. Doesn't Python have a way to simply execute another module?

Comment: Importing the first time *is* executing.

Comment: By importing the execution of all of `modA.py` and running it in `modB.py` as required.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That doesn't seem to be the case in practice. I have a bunch of print statements in modA.py and none of them are printed out just by importing it.

Comment: Then you've broken something else.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks! You're right. I wasn't importing it correctly.

Comment: This is interesting as coming from a C background I've always thought of Python "import" as analogous to "include" where you don't "execute" the header file.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've updated the question. The solution suggested doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: What's the practical reason for your question?  You can easily just embed the code you want to run into a function. Then just call that function from modA in modB. Like @SnowBG did in his answer. And I don't get why this does not fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You must import as a library.

### modA.py:

```
def addiction(a,b):
    '''Sum two numbers. (int, int)'''
    return(a+b)
```

### modB.py:

```
import modA

print(modA.addiction(2,3))
```

### output:

5

Comment: Thanks. I know how to import it. How do I run all of modA.py from modB.py? What is the command I should use?

Comment: Now you use it as a normal library... you must call the methods on modA.py on modB.py

Comment: I made an example for you. Hope helped.

Comment: The key point of this answer is that you don’t generally “execute a module”; you define functions in a module, then call those functions.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of at this point is

```
import imp

#first execution of modA.py
import modA.py

print "some ModB.py stuff here"

#second execution of modA.py
imp.reload(modA.py)
```

This solution is very messy, because now you have to keep track of when you're executing a module for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neat solution that works nicely:

**module_a** is the module you want to run from **module_b**

so I'm assuming you're running **module_a** from the terminal with a command
like:

```
$ python module_a.py
```

This means you have an if name == main: in your code that allows you to run the module from your terminal:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    lines = read_addresses()
    json_data = create_request_string(lines)
    response = get_response(json_data)
    matrix = durations_matrix(response)
    matrix = np.matrix(matrix)
    print(matrix)
```

Your code block is obviously different.

Move your code block to a run_module() function instead and execute it within
your name == main block, this code will now run the same when you call it from your terminal:

```
def run_module():
    lines = read_addresses()
    json_data = create_request_string(lines)
    response = get_response(json_data)
    matrix = durations_matrix(response)
    matrix = np.matrix(matrix)
    return(matrix)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(run_module())
```

Now you can run **module_a** from **module_b** like so:

Inside of **module_b** you have:

import the module

call the run_module() function

```
import module_a
matrix = module_a.run_module()
```